# SQL JOIN and SUM function causes huge number differences

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sum, amazon-redshift

I've trying to get the sum of each customer on every month.
However, whenever I join the tables with the calendar table, I get a very high number.
The order of the sales are the same.. so I think the sum function is being used several times..

Does anyone know how to fix this..?

[This code causes a smaller number]

```
SELECT 
s.payer_account_id
, s.month_id
, SUM(s.sales_revenue) AS total_sales
FROM dev.assessment.fact_sales_revenue s
GROUP BY 
s.payer_account_id
, s.month_id
ORDER BY total_sales;
```

Results are :

Payeraccountid   month_id  total_sales

1                201903    -248182

2                201907    -196241

3                202008    -172717

4                201908    -160415

[The results ascending are the same but this code causes a huge number]

```
SELECT 
    s.payer_account_id
    , s.month_id
    , SUM(s.sales_revenue) AS total_sales
    , c.month_code
    , c.year_id
    , c.prior_year_id
    FROM dev.assessment.fact_sales_revenue s
INNER JOIN dev.assessment.dim_calendar c
ON s.month_id = c.month_id
GROUP BY 
    s.payer_account_id
    , s.month_id
    , c.month_code
    , c.year_id
    , c.prior_year_id
ORDER BY total_sales;
```

Results are :
Payeraccountid  |month_id | total_sales | month_code
1            |    201903   | -7693657     |  MAR

2            |   201907   | -5887230     | JUL

3            |  202008   | -5181517     |  AUG

4            |   201908   | -4972869     | AUG

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Two SQL LEFT JOINS produce incorrect result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464037/two-sql-left-joins-produce-incorrect-result)

Comment: [mre] [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right about it. Your data is multiplied by almost 30 times in each row.
Why don't you join your primary results with `dev.assessment.dim_calendar c`.
Something like:

```
SELECT a.*, c.<your_necessary_columns> FROM (
SELECT 
    s.payer_account_id
    , s.month_id
    , SUM(s.sales_revenue) AS total_sales
    FROM dev.assessment.fact_sales_revenue s
    YOUR CLAUSES) a 
    INNER JOIN dev.assessment.dim_calendar c
    ON a.month_id = c.month_id
    YOUR CLAUSES
```

I had previously asked for some minimum reproducible data. Without it I can just give you an  execution plan not the exact query.
Good luck! Let me know if it works.